# How to program/configure ADF5356 with out using the evaluation board?

Tags: analog, serial, microchip, programming, microwave

I understand how to program ADF5356 on the evaluation board

http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/EVAL-ADF5356.html

Using

http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/sdp-s.html?doc=EV-ADF5356SD1Z-UG-1087.pdf

and the available software.

But how would I program the ADF5356 if I purchased it in this package:

https://www.xmicrowave.com/product/xm-a5y9-0409d/

Or if I just purchased the ADF5356 chip to use in another circuit.

I like the look of the xmicrowave products, does any here have some experience with them?

Comment: It is a serial addressed set of registers. [ADF5356](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF5356.pdf). It is all in the spec. If this doesn't make sense, you probably don't want to go there. That is one pricey chip!

Comment: @lakeweb I guess I do not know how to interface to it to set the registers. All the software does on the PC with the eval board is allow you to set the registers through the PC software via the USB interface of the SDP-S. I just don't see how to do that on the xmicrowave solution. I'm actually trying to save some money because the cost of staying ignorant is to purchase a different option that costs $2000. But then its quite a bit more $$$ if I decide to scale up a bit.

Comment: Hi, what you need to do is learn about pumping serial data out of a micro. It is done all the time for I2C and SPI. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=microprocessor+communication+interface) 'microprocessor communication interface'.

Comment: You may consider 'bit-bang'. I depends on what your data source is. I did notice that even though digi-key listed it at $284, AD says $54@100. Not a bad price for this chip. I like what it can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of the Xmicrowave PCB it says: -

> Control of all on-chip registers is through a simple 3-wire interface

And in the ADF5356 data sheet it shows this: -

[image]

So you need to add an MCU that can send serial data to the ADF5356 via the three wire port highlighted in red. All ADi's range of fractional and integer PLLs use the same method so if something isn't clear on one data sheet go look on another like the ADF4002 or the ADF4111 (simpler devices that use the same interface).

Comment: thank you. Should the MCU send the serial data at every power on?

Comment: @axawire yes, every time power is applied but, it doesn’t hurt to do it more often in case of brown outs.